# How can I use regex to find and replace all text in lines while leaving a string and whitespace between two delimiters intact?

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I'm not that great with Regex...

I have thousands of lines in an XML doc that are like this (whitespaces are intentional as they are there in XML):

```
<col id="7" type="TEXT"> Speaker</col>
<col id="7" type="TEXT"> Monitor</col>
<col id="7" type="TEXT"> TV</col>
<col id="7" type="TEXT"> Amp</col>
```

and want to do basically the inverse of this:
[^>]+(?![^<]*>)

I want to do a replace that leaves everything between the first ">" and the second "<" intact.

And wrap that string (and whitespace) to end up with, for example:

```
<outline text=" Speaker"></outline>
<outline text=" Monitor"></outline>
```

and so on.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Try `<[^>]*>([^<]*)<[^>]*>` and replace with `<outline text="$1"></outline>`

Comment: In which language are you implementing the regex?

Comment: The best tools to manage XML files are not **sed** or **awk** with regex, but **xslproc**.

Comment: @PierreFrançois am doing a find and replace in Atom so I suppose that is the Oniguruma flavor. Although I plan on putting those expressions into the JS of the Special Character Replacer package to automate my find/replace operations.

Comment: @PierreFrançois unfortunately those tools are a bit beyond me at this point.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this does work. Thank you! I would pick it as the best answer if I have the clout here. But I don't so I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Atom, you may simply search for `<[^>]*>([^<]*)<[^>]*>` and replace with `<outline text="$1"></outline>`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AQNxuO/1).

**Details**

- `<[^>]*>` - `<`, 0 or more chars other than `>` and then a `>`
- `([^<]*)` - *Capturing* group 1: any 0 or more chars other than `>` and then a `>`
- `<[^>]*>` - `<`, 0 or more chars other than `>` and then a `>`

The `$1` in the replacement pattern is a backreference to the value stored in Group 1.